# Should I round my database field sizes to a the nearest multiple of a base 2 number?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I have seen in some example databases people like to round field sizes to a multiple of a base 2 number (e.g. varchar(32) or varchar(64) ) as if it is giving them better performance or space utilization. Is there any benefit to this practice? Or is this just people being pedantic?

Thanks for the lookin

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In MySQL, the length should really always be 255 or 65,535 (unless there are type-specific reasons for choosing a different length).  There are two different ways of storing character strings.  For lengths up to 255, the length is stored in one byte rather than two, saving a byte of storage.

In a `varchar`, the length is the maximum length.  Values are stored on the page based on their actual length.  So, the maximum length just doesn't affect the storage of anything else, with the exception of 1- or 2-byte lengths (depending on whether the maximum is <= 255 or >= 256).  (The length being a power of two -- with the exception of 256 -- has no affect on the storage.)

As for setting lengths as powers of two.  I am guilty of this on many occasions.  It is an old habit borne of wanting to keep the fields aligned on byte boundaries.  The idea was to keep fields aligned on 4- or 8- byte boundaries, because this is more optimal for the CPU (think "C" programming language).  This either prevented unnecessary space when an integer or floating point value required 4- or 8- byte alignment (so some bytes would be missed) or unnecessary overhead to copy bytes from unaligned space to aligned space.  Of course, as I just noted, this logic has no basis for databases, because the maximum length does not effect the actual storage on the page.

Another reason why this has no significance is that the `varchar` type actually stores one or two bytes more than the length.  The database takes care of the conversion from the physical format on the page to the physical format in memory.  Trying to "optimize" this process is way more effort than it is worth.

Comment: +1. The length of a varchar() field should make little difference.

Comment: interesting.. do you have found leads in the mysql documentation or is this a educated guess?

Comment: actually i prefer to choose varchar length as x power of 2, it's more intuitive for Dev guys. :/

Comment: Nice answer—just adding a link to the documentation : [Data type storage requirements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not it works. I didn't believe it until I verified it myself. I built a database with two fields in two tables, both indexed, and loaded them full of data. One field was VARCHAR(100) and the other was VARCHAR(256).

When querying the tables, the field that was 256 performed better.

The reason this works is because of the block size when reading the disk, it matches up and so it's not reading a partial block at a time.

Comment: Do you have some empirical evidence to back that statement up? Database pages are usually something like 8192 bytes... AND most pages should be in RAM anyway

Comment: @Mitch, this was a few years ago so I'd have to build the example again, but I might be able to get to that this week.

Comment: @MitchWheat . . . This would be absolutely correct, but it has nothing to do with powers of 2.  Lengths of 256 happen to be the first length where MySQL uses two bytes for the length rather than 1.

Comment: @MitchWheat . . . Now that gets complicated.  It depends on what the data is in the fields (was the data always 100 bytes? or were 100 bytes being compared to 256 bytes?).  How full were the pages?  It depends on what the CPU has to do to decode the length.  And, the proper comparison for 100 bytes would really be 128 bytes, rather than 256.